# Magento 2 checkout returns "Shipping address is missing. please try and again"

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

In magento 2 checkout,"Shipping address is missing. please try and again" error getting thrown in "set-payment-information" call

this happens only when the page is loaded first time or after a placing a order.

Any suggestions please..

Comment: Are you trying to place an order with customer or guest user?

Comment: As a guest @quickshiftin

Comment: is there any external shipping method you're using?

Comment: No.. Table rate only